# What exact code-point conversion does string literal prefix "r" imply (Python 3.4)?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode, escaping

What Unicode code-point conversion does the stringprefix "r" (or "R") actually perform on string literals in Python 3 (literals/files parsed as UTF-8)?

I am using Python 3.4 on Windows 7.

I want to to parse this "evil" path on Windows:

```
>>> a = 'c:\a\b\f\v' 
>>> a
'c:\x07\x08\x0c\x0b'
>>> a.decode(encoding='utf-8')
b'c:\x07\x08\x0c\x0b'
```

With the prefix "r", I get:

```
>>> b = r'c:\a\b\f\v'
>>> b
c:\a\b\f\v
```

My question: How do I mimic (exactly) the "raw" code-point mapping/conversion on a Unicode string object in memory (not a string literal)? I could use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans), but what exact mapping are we talking about then?

Context: Generally, I want to be to support all kinds of weird directory names on Windows (and other platforms) being handed to my application as strings via command line parameters. How can I?

Comment: It is a **syntax**, the results are still strings. Just like you can use `0xFF` or `255` to define an integer using two different forms (hex and decimal), `r'...'` allows you to define a string value. As such there is no 'mapping' taking place here.

Comment: The syntax disables escape sequences such as `\b` (the bell character) normally used when interpreting string literals.

Comment: When a user enters a string on a prompt, it is not a Python string literal. It is just data. No escape sequences are interpreted that way. No paths using bell characters or form-feed characters will be used.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for your comments, but a string literal is also just data ... Any string literal given (be it in file or console) is by default parsed as though being encoded as UTF-8 (is it not?). Actually, a string literal can be considered as a `bytes` object (it obviously not a string). I simply seek the exact functional form of what the prefix "r" does with the UTF-8 octets before decoding to a string (or what happens without it applied). Such a method should actually exist on `bytes` objects. (so this has nothing to do with unicode code-point conversion after all -- my bad).

Comment: Using a raw string literal does nothing. The Python parser takes the *already decoded source text* and creates a Python string object from it.

Comment: It is only a string literal if it is hard-coded in the program.  The issue is with the python parser - you would only get the issue with data from a file or console if you were using something like `exec` or `eval`.

Comment: @OleThomsenBuus: Python source code can use any codec; just include a  [PEP 263 header](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) to specify a different codec. In an interactive console the terminal is determines what codec to use (on POSIX systems, the `LC_CTYPE` environment variable is consulted).

Comment: (to anyone) So I obviously pressed the "Ask Question" button prematurely here. I should have done more reading before doing that. Anyway, I learned something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What Unicode code-point conversion does the string prefix "r" (or "R") actually perform on string literals in Python 3 (literals/files parsed as UTF-8)?*

Python 3 native strings are already UTF-8 (by default), no conversions are done with the `r` prefix.

*Without* the `r` prefix then conversions are done to characters prefixed `\`.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

```
\a gives the code for a bell (a - alarm)  0x07
\b gives the code for a backspace         0x08
\f is a form feed                         0x0c
\v is a vertical tab                      0x0b
```

So, if you have (what you call) weird Windows path names, then always use raw strings, or use a `/` for a directory separator instead.  However you only need to worry about those that are hard-coded because they are parsed by python, those entered by the user should be fine.

Edit:

if you do this:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.normpath('C:\bash')
'C:\x08ash'

>>> var = input("Enter a filename: ")
Enter a filename: C:\bash
>>> print(var)
C:\bash
>>> os.path.normpath(var)
'C:\\bash'
```

Double back-slashing has the same effect as using raw strings.

Comment: Thanks. Take a look at my comment above. It makes it a bit more clear what I seek. This whole thing originated when trying to use `os.path.normpath`, which seems to convert "\a" to "\x07".

Comment: @OleThomsenBuus: but how are you passing the path into `normpath`?  If it is a string literal, then it is not `norm path` doing the changes, but the python parser.  See edit.

Comment: Okay - I see your point now. This all started in an IPython Notebook running in Chrome, and I got the same in the python interpreter. I had not considered that it was the parser that was messing with me. With input(), I guess you send the individual characters through the console directly and thus avoid the parser doing stuff that it would otherwise do with a literal. Correct? :-)

Comment: Yup, you got it.  The parser only kicks-in when the program is compiled, at runtime there is no further parsing (unless you use messy stuff like `exec` and `eval`).

Comment: @OleThomsenBuus: sorry, I didn't flag you for my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 'c:\a\b\f\v'
'c:\x07\x08\x0c\x0b'
```

When you type a string literal like this *in Python source code*, you need to either double the backslashes or use `r` for a raw string.

```
>>> 'c:\\a\\b\\f\\v'
'c:\\a\\b\\f\\v'
>>> r'c:\a\b\f\v'
'c:\\a\\b\\f\\v'

>>> print('c:\\a\\b\\f\\v')
c:\a\b\f\v
>>> print(r'c:\a\b\f\v')
c:\a\b\f\v
```

*This has nothing to do with Unicode.* It's the Python interpreter which is evaluating backslash escape sequences in string literals.

This is only the case with string literals in your source code. If you read a string from the command line or from a file you don't have to worry about any of this. Python does not interpret backslashes in these cases.